# Does anyone know why my Bootstrap 4 order classes aren't working?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have the first column display first on desktop, and have the second column display first on mobile.

```
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
  <div class="row layer-bg no-margin">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 order-sm-12 order-lg-1 pb-5">
      <img src="img/alien.jpg" class="img-fluid float-right profile" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 order-sm-1 order-lg-12 home-right">
      <h3 class="mt-5">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      <p class="my-4">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      <button type="button" class="btnmt-4" onclick="showDiv()"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this in codepend, it seems to working fine. Maybe you can add some screenshots of current & expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in defining the order classes. For example you are using: order-sm-12. This is not valid. In my snippet im using order-lg-(x) to define the order after lg (so even on xl). The order-1 or order-2 defines everything from the smallest breakpoint to in this case lg

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 order-2 order-lg-1"></div>
<div class="col-12 order-1 order-lg-2"></div>
</div>
```